# Cannot remove index in Titan over DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, titan

I created a mixed index on Titan 1.0 with Dynamo DB backend and Elasticsearch and I'm trying to remove it using the following code

```
public static void removeIndex(TitanGraph graph, String indexStr) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    TitanManagement m = graph.openManagement();
    TitanGraphIndex nameIndex = m.getGraphIndex(indexStr);
    Preconditions.checkState(nameIndex!=null, "index "+ indexStr +" doesn't exist");
    TitanManagement.IndexJobFuture futureDisable = m.updateIndex(nameIndex, SchemaAction.DISABLE_INDEX);

    m.commit();
    graph.tx().commit();

    futureDisable.get();

    // Block until the SchemaStatus transitions from to DISABLED
    ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, indexStr)
            .status(SchemaStatus.DISABLED).call();

    // Delete the index using TitanManagement
    m = graph.openManagement();
    nameIndex = m.getGraphIndex(indexStr);
    TitanManagement.IndexJobFuture futureRemove =
            m.updateIndex(nameIndex, SchemaAction.REMOVE_INDEX);
    m.commit();
    graph.tx().commit();

    Preconditions.checkState(futureRemove!=null,
            "Couldn't remove index/es because seems like indexes were not disabled.");  // fails here.
    futureRemove.get();

    m = graph.openManagement();
    nameIndex = m.getGraphIndex(indexStr);
    Preconditions.checkArgument(nameIndex==null);

}
```

The key doesn't get removed. I get this warning indicating that the index never gets disabled.

```
---
INFO  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.GraphIndexStatusWatcher  - Some key(s) on index verticesIndex do not currently have status DISABLED: position=INSTALLED
INFO  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.GraphIndexStatusWatcher  - Timed out (PT1M) while waiting for index verticesIndex to converge on status DISABLED
```

[WARNING]

The code fails on the precondition test.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was using `position` to define a property key which is a reserved keyword in DynamoDB.

The only way was to:

- Delete all DynamoDB tables of Titan from the web console,
- change 'position' to 'fieldPosition',
- and start my code to create tables and indexes from scratch.